# Authentication and Autherization using ESB and IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to follow up with the samples as mentioned in: 
http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/05/authentication-and-authorization-with.html

After following up with everystep, when I try to test it using TryIt, the Identity Server  throws the following error: 
Access Denied. Please Login First.

The Servers are running at their default configuration, except for the ports - ESB on 9443 and IS on 9445. 
ESB version: 4.5.1
IS version: 3.2.3

Kindly let me know what configuration is missing. 
Thanks, 
Praveen

Comment: I did not configure the User Store properly. The ESB user store had to be mapped to the one used by IS.

Answer (score 0):

refer [this](http://srinathsview.blogspot.com/2012/05/authentication-and-authorization.html) to understand more on Authentication and Autherization using ESB and IS Patterns.

furthermore, [this slide](http://www.slideshare.net/wso2.org/security-patterns-with-wso2-esb) set has interesting Security patterns with ESB